# How to use .value on reactive nested objects in Vue 3's Composition API?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm wondering where it's correct to use `.value` when referencing reactive objects if they are nested 2+ levels deep. Do you put `.value` on the base object and then access sub-keys off that? Or do you put it on the deepest key?

Here is an example:

```js
import { reactive, computed } from 'vue'

const someObj = reactive({
    a: {
        b: {
            c: 1
        }
    }
})

const doubleSomeObj = computed(() => {
    return someObj.value.a.b.c * 2
    // Or... someObj.a.b.c.value * 2
    // Or something else?
})
```

In the above code, in the computed property `doubleSomeObj`, it references the nested object `someObj`.

When referencing the various keys in that nested object `someObj`, at what level is it correct to put `.value`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.value` is only used on [`ref`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/refs-api.html#ref)s. The `reactive` object's subproperties can be used without employing `.value`, so you could just directly multiply it in your `computed` prop:

```js
const doubleSomeObj = computed(() => {
    return someObj.a.b.c * 2
})
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/accessing-reactive-subproperties-kotkm?file=/src/App.vue:384-416)